# Android Restricted Profiles. How to restrict play store?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, restricted-profiles

Is there any way to stop play store in the restricted profile ? I want internet to be accessible but i dont want the restricted user to download any apps.

Comment: Can't you just hide the play store? Or disable it in settings?

Answer (score 2):

**Restricted profiles** (as opposed to a 'full' user profile), by design, **do not have access to Google Play**, and a host of other Google services that need a Google account to tie setting to.  You can even restrict the user to as many or few apps as you'd please, based from the main account.

Internet access is NOT restricted in any way